# Get data when tableview item clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one TableView, and inside that I have another TableView, in which each cell contains a switch.

When I click on that switch, I want to send the data for that cell to my view controller. How can I achieve this?

Here is my approach:

I created a protocol from where I am sending position clicked from inner TableView to outer TableView, but I am not able to get the complete object, and I don't know how to proceed further.

Inner TableView cell switch clicked :

```
@IBAction func switchClicked(_ sender: UISwitch) {
//position clicked
   print("inside cell clicked>>\(sender.tag)")
    cellDelegate?.tableViewCellClicked(position: sender.tag, type: 
 "SwitchClicked")
}
```

Method call in outer TableView class :

```
func tableViewCellClicked(position: Int, type: Any) {
        print("position\(position)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure for your switch function, inside the cell have a

```
var switchAction: () -> Void?
```

And inside the cell switch function call `switchAction?()`, Now while setting the cell set a `switchAction` for example

```
func foo() { } 
Cell.switchAction = foo
```

Now when u click switch action `foo` function will trigger you can pass w/e you want with that.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.i never try closure.so can we declare the closure outer tableview cell and call that inside inner tableview?

Comment: Yea you can keep passing it to whatever